# How do you allow the map to zoom more than the map actually has

Tags: ios, dictionary, offline, mapbox, tilemill

We have an iPhone app that uses mapbox to display offline maps created using tilemill. In previous versions of Mapbox the user could zoom in as much as they wanted even though the map had only be created to a level 15 zoom. This was important to us as we overlay a GPX track and waypoints over the map and it is important we can zoom in to view that information. The map of course distorted but wasn't a major issue.

We have created various maps with tilemill however we are finding that to be able to zoom in to the level we require needs a map of 100s of megabytes which is not feasible for an iPhone app. In previous editions of Mapbox the user was able to zoom in further than the zoom set when creating the app.

Is there any way to zoom into the maps further? or are there any other alternatives to view offline maps on a mobile device?

Thanks.

Additional comment: Another option would be to hide all data at zoom levels above 17 so that the map would go blank above zoom 17. i.e. user can zoom in but once they past a certain point the map goes blank. Therefore not requiring the thousands of tile images above zoom level 17. How could we do that in Tilemill?